# qTip2: how to make a tooltip move to left when a link is close to the right side of the browser?

Tags: javascript, qtip2

I am using qTip 2.0.1 for displaying tooltips.

I make the tooltip show up in the bottom right of a link. The issue is that when the link is close to the right side of the browser, the tooltip box looks squeezed and ugly.

Can I configure qTip to make it auto-adjust its tooltip position to bottom-left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the collision detection as demonstrated on their demo:

```
position: {
        at: $('#at').val(),
        my: $('#my').val(),
        viewport: $(window),
        adjust: {
            method: [your method]
        }
    },
...
```

[Documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/#adjust.method)